PostgreSQL, time series - Looking for a way to omit timestamps if a row contains one or more zeroes
Sorry for the bump, I am still searching for a method to omit rows based on specific conditions though. Is it even possible?
I'm tinkering in a tool called Grafana with the aim of one day creating useful visualizations, tapping into a database (I haven't set up myself) containing temperature reads from various sources in a factory.
The problem: Once in a while a sensor fails to report its value, and becomes recorded as zero instead. Note: They are only shown as blanks/nulls in the output table because of condition WHERE value <> 0. However, regardless of zero/null, they are still wrong and cause problems in graphs and calculations. I therefore want all affected row gone. Losing an occational timestamp is less bad than including one with errors.
So I'm looking for a query condition/method to say that if a row contains zeroes in one (or more) of its columns, then the entire timestamp should be omitted.
Currently my query looks like this:
SELECT 
  time_bucket('20 sec', time) AS time, --20 second time interval
  part AS metric, --AS metric makes the column labels look neat (somehow)
  MAX(value) --pick max value of part within each interval
FROM temp 
WHERE
  temp.machineno = '$MachineNo' --grafana dashboard variable -> select machine from drop menu
    AND $__timeFilter(time) --grafana dashboard filter -> select time window from drop menu
      AND value <> 0 
GROUP BY time, part
ORDER BY time

It outputs a table like this:Table The names and numbers of columns vary depending on which machine is selected, so a method where I don't have to know or specify anything about the columns would be preferable. (Note: machines are selected from a drop-down menu in grafana, and is what '$MachineNo' refers to.)
As a graph it looks like this:
Graph
We can see the two blank from the table as gaps in the graph. Now Grafana has a button to smooth such gaps over vizually, but it doesn't remove them from table - which means they are still there to cause problems if I were to run calculations with these numbers.
Instead of a table like this:
Unfiltered table
I'd like a filtered table like this:
Filtered table
I can't really account for everything I've tried. Have mostly read a lot, and tried a few things now and then, but nothing that has worked. I am able to find info on how to omit columns, but very little pertaining to rows. I tried using DELETE once... Not sure if it would have worked, but luckily it did not... I don't have authoritiy to delete anything from the database, and I don't want to either. I just want to filter out obvious mistakes from the output table.

WHERE value <> 0 is doing exactly what you want, it completely ignores rows with a value of 0, as if the entire row was gone. They are not included at all in the result. "they are still there to cause problems if I were to run calculations with these numbers." - can you show what calculations you are doing that give wrong results?

"my query looks like this", "It outputs a table like this" - no it doesn't. It's not clear how these correspond to each other. Does Grafana do some additional pivoting there? Then this is not something you can solve in Postgres (alone).

@Bergi, IIRC Grafana automatically pivots data, if dataset has columns 'time, metric, value'. Or based on example here, name of the last column probably doesn't matter.

Sorry, don't know how I read this, but completely misunderstood your idea.

@Bergi - Ah... I suspected Grafana did something "extra" behind the scenes, but wasn't able to articulate it. It appears it does pivot the table. I think markalex is spot on in illustrating what's happening in this example of his: link

@Bergi Okay... So, since the table does pivot, and this means that my problem can't be solved with postgres alone... Do you have any pointers on what it would take? (Not necessarily a ready-made solution, but some kind of general idea of what I could/should do/look into?)

@kreaturen yes, you either need to solve this in Grafana, or you do the pivoting in postgres already (like you showed), then it'll be possible to process the query results to remove those result rows where any sensor had a problem

It didn't jump into mind previously, but now that you asked I think Grafana's Transformation Filter data by values should be able to do exactly what you need.

@markalex - That kind of works, but not in a general way. I managed to filter out the rows I wanted with it, on one machine, but the moment I changed machine it broke because the other machine's column names weren't exactly the same. Now I could fix that, but then the first one would break instead. Would be interesting to know how the filter does it though, because it does exactly what I want... Just not for any column, regardless of how many or which one affected (which I also kind of need it to do)

@Bergi - You mean query my query? The first query would pivot the table into the format I need for the time series, whereas the second would filter it? Hmm... Now that I understand a bit better what's been going on, I think that could possibly work (if Grafana permits it)

You can try following query:
with bucketed as (
  SELECT time_bucket('20 sec', time) AS time,   --20 second time interval
         part                        AS metric, --AS metric makes the column labels look neat (somehow)
         MAX(value)                  AS val     --pick max value of part within each interval
    FROM temp 
   WHERE temp.machineno = '$MachineNo' --grafana dashboard variable -> select machine from drop menu
     AND $__timeFilter(time)           --grafana dashboard filter -> select time window from drop menu
   GROUP BY time, part
)
SELECT t1.* FROM bucketed t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
    FROM bucketed t2 
   WHERE t1.time = t2.time
     AND t2.val = 0
)

Here I get values put into time buckets into CTE, and then use this CTE in conjunction with NOT EXISTS to filter out all timestamps where any of the values is 0.
Please notice that I'm not familiar with time series implementation in Postgres, and couldn't find clear documentation for time_bucket functions, so simply assumed that it returns same value for all metrics. If this is not the case, line WHERE t1.time=t2.time might need some adjustment.

Sorry for the late reply, but holy cow, you did it! Love the CTE, very useful to know for later. I think I follow the next bit too. Looks like it creates two instances of 'bucketed' (so that the timestamps can finally be compared against "themselves"), and excludes all identical timestamps if it finds a zero in at least one of them. Since they're all gone, no gaps carries over once Grafana pivots to table afterwards. It's perfect, thank you so much :)

Actually, there is just one thing I'm uncertain about: SELECT 1... What does '1' actually refer to? Is it the first column of 't2' (time), or does it mean something else? I guess the reason I ask is that, is because it looks at t2.value also, so if '1' means t2.time and only t2.time is selected, how can it find t2.value? SELECT t2.* worked also.

@kreaturen, 1 means literally number 1 there, nothing else. NOT EXISTS filters based on presence or absence of rows in dataset, and it doesn't care what's in those rows.

Also, I forgot... time_bucket comes from a thirdparty extension called "Timescale", specifically made to improve postgres time series. Honestly it's far too above my level... I try to avoid relying on code I don't understand, but in this I have no choice, it has to be there.

Really? Hah... Thanks for the clarification - More abstract than I anticipated, but good to know.

Looking at the table you've shown I think the value is null rater than 0.
Try
and value <> 0
and value is not null

If this isn't the case I would need a table definition and some example data to test with.

Yeah no, the source value is sent as 0 (when the sensors fail). It just gets replaced by null in the output table now because of and value <> 0
Unfortunately I'm not entirly sure how to provide you what you need... What is a table definition (Sorry, total noob question)? As for test data, could for instance a csv print out be that?

It's possible it's a quirk of grafana, rather than the SQL you're using. The simplest thing to do is recreate the table with the data you want filtered locally and just run the query without grafana in the way. I don't see anything else wrong with the query

Looking at the table you shared again, I think the reason it's showing is because other values exist for this time period like ambient temp and cabinet temp so the filtering out nulls like you ask would lose the data from the other sensors.

Sorry for the late reply, I'm just working part-time and not tinkering with this every day... Your last idea is spot on I think, it's what I'm suspecting as well. That's why excluding all data from the affected timestamps would be a desired outcome for me - I'm just not how to do it, or if it's even possible?

A missing timestamp here and there wouldn't noticably affect the visualization, but a single missing/wrong datapoint within a included timestamp does.

How to check the values of the columns of a table without knowing exactly the names of the columns.
See example.
We do not use column names for filter values 0 or null.
Query steps

Aggregate entire row to JSON.
Expand json into a set of JSON values
Filter json values. There null values from table converted by json to 'null' json value. this value converted to text and compared with text'null'.  If Id column or any other column has value=0 this row also filtered out. You can add additional check to exists(...).

Test data
create table test (id int, val1 int,val2 int,val3 int);
insert into test values
 (1,10,20,30)
,(2,11,21,29)
,(3, 9, 0,31)
,(4, 9, 20,null)
;

Query
select *
from test t
where not exists( 
  select key::text k,value::text v from json_each(row_to_json(t.*)) eatr
  where value::text='null' or cast(coalesce(value::text,'') as int)=0 )

Output is



id
val1
val2
val3




1
10
20
30


2
11
21
29



For the opposite condition exists in same query
select *
from test t
where exists( 
  select key::text k,value::text v from json_each(row_to_json(t.*)) eatr
  where value::text='null' or cast(coalesce(value::text,'') as int)=0 )

result is



id
val1
val2
val3




3
9
0
31


4
9
20
null



If columns contains non-digit values,  WHERE conditions may by adopted like
value::text='null' or (value::text similar to '[0-9.]{1,}' and cast(value::text as int)=0)

or
value::text='null'  
  or (value::text similar to '[0-9]{1,}[.]{0,1}[0-9]{0,}' and cast(value::text as float)=0.0)

Fiddle here
Your query
SELECT 
  time_bucket('20 sec', time) AS time, --20 second time interval
  part AS metric, --AS metric makes the column labels look neat (somehow)
  MAX(value) --pick max value of part within each interval
FROM temp 
WHERE
  temp.machineno = '$MachineNo' --grafana dashboard variable -> select machine from drop menu
  AND $__timeFilter(time) --grafana dashboard filter -> select time window from drop menu
  AND -- value <> 0 
     not exists( 
    select key::text k,value::text v from json_each(row_to_json(temp.*)) eatr
    where value::text='null' or cast(value::text as int)=0 
   )
GROUP BY time, part
ORDER BY time


Your example uses pivoted data. But pivoting is happening on Grafana. Please notice that OP's original query returns dataset with columns time, metric, max(value)

My example do not affect on dataset columns. Only WHERE clause. Explain,pls, what you mean.

I mean that your example works with columns as they are presented on the screenshot, but actual columns in db and in resulting dataset are different. Maybe this demo will help: https://dbfiddle.uk/tIT-hK7x

Perhaps OP creates the table in the way you specified. However, its problem is that it has to exclude rows where null or 0 is present in any of the metrics (metric1,metric2, metric3 in your demo). This means that he is looking at an already pivoted table. However, your objection may well be correct. An explanation is required from the OP.

@ValNik Thank you for the reply. I haven't tested it yet (I will), but it appears markalex is correct about Grafana pivoting the table "post-query", and so it probably won't work. I wasn't aware of this because I don't understand Grafana that well yet either, but his fiddle is spot on.

@markalex - Your fiddle is spot on. I didn't really understand that this was happening. (I mean I saw it, but didn't fully understand why or what to call it). Do you know of any ways/tricks to filter out rows with zeroes after such a pivot though?
